# Как записать данные в файл с консоли

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Мне надо создать метод, который будет записывать все содержимое введенное пользователем с консоли в файл по заданному пути, не перезаписывая содержимое файла. И запись в файл должна производиться после ввода команды wr в отдельной строке. Метод я сделал, но в результате его работы, срабатывает сразу первый cath. Когда дебажу программу показывает - процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.

```
public static void writeToFileFromConsole(String path){

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

        FileWriter writer = null;
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;

        System.out.println("Enter file content to write in the file:");

        try {
            String command = "wr";
            String line;
            line = br.readLine();
            if ((line = br.readLine()).equals(command)) {
                writer = new FileWriter(path, true);
                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);

                bufferedWriter.append("\n");
                bufferedWriter.append(line);
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Can't write to file with path " + path);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
                br.close();
                if (writer != null){
                    writer.close();
                }
                if (bufferedWriter != null){
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.err.println("File with path " + path + " not found" );
            }
        }
    }
```

Подскажите в чём моя ошибка ? И как исправить, чтобы в файл записывались данные введенные в консоли.

Comment: ты пытаешься в цикле вызывать `writeToFileFromConsole`? ............. вообще потоки надо закрывать в обратном порядке. в начале надо закрыть `bufferedWriter` а потом `writer`........... + можно для чтения/записи использовать try with resources

Comment: нет, в цикле я не вызываю ... создал класс Demo и в нем тестирую работу программы, просто вызывая этот метод

Comment: И закрытие потоков в обратном порядке ничего не дало.

Comment: Попробуйте перезагрузить комп, возможно у вас в процессе отладки повис процесс и винда не дает больше доступа к файлу, может вы забыли закрыть запущенный процесс в дебагере или открыли какой-то программой файл на редактирования

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверил ваш код, ошибок никаких не возникло, кроме исключения сообщавшего, что файла не существует.

Переделал, чтобы его не возникало:

```
private static void writeToFileFromConsole(String path) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter file content to write in the file:");

    try (OutputStream output = Files
            .newOutputStream(
                    Paths.get(path),
                    StandardOpenOption.APPEND,
                    StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
         BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(output)) {

        String line;
        while (!"rw".equalsIgnoreCase(line = reader.readLine())) {
            outputStream.write(System.lineSeparator().getBytes());
            outputStream.write(line.getBytes());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: А что в моём варианте не правильно ? После запуска метода, в консоли выводится - Enter file content to write in the file:
hello
wr
Can't write to file with path C:\Users\Skorodielov\Desktop\Test1.txt

Comment: проверяйте пути, либо он не верен либо нет прав на запись в этот файл

Comment: проверял... я этот файл сам и создал и записывал в него данные, только двумя методами... одним считывал данные с консоли, а другим записывал в этот файл... а теперь попробовал соединить два метода в один и не записывает

Comment: Попробуйте перезагрузить комп, возможно у вас в процессе отладки повис процесс и винда не дает больше доступа к файлу, может вы забыли закрыть запущенный процесс в дебагере или открыли какой-то программой файл на редактирования

Comment: записывает не первую строку, а вторую... должно записывать при вводе команды wr, строку , которую набираю в консоли, а в итоге записывает в файл wr ... не пойму почему так...

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь. Разобрался, надо было добавить переменную line1 и её передавать на запись в файл